# How do I flash a color?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIButton, and when tapped I want it to flash a background color, then return to its old color after some time.

Its old color isn't always the same, so I made a class variable.

Here is my current code, but I'm not sure how to achieve the time delay:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   ///stuff
   var oldColor: UIColor?

   @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       oldColor = sender.backgroundColor
       flashColor(sender, UIColor.green)
   }

   func flashColor(btn: UIButton, color: UIColor) {
       btn.backgroundColor = color
       wait(100ms) //I really have no idea how to do this part 
       btn.backgroundColor = oldColor
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use my [`delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994) function:

```
   btn.backgroundColor = color
   delay(0.1) { 
       btn.backgroundColor = oldColor
   }
```

Comment: You should seriously put this on Github Gist! This is amazing, thanks, I'll accept this once SO lets me